# DNS setup for using shopify and you own server/hosting

Tags: dns, hosting, shopify

Need some help figuring out how to set up the DNS for a domain to run shopify along with our current server/hosting aswell.

Example: 
www.testlight.com or testlight.com (will show our shopify store)

BUT we need to keep our current server (which the domain a record is pointing to, and this is what shopify recommends to delete and replace with their ip, which is: 204.93.213.45)

~ as our current server hosts some images/files we need to keep it,so we need that to function as it is. 
So basically run our current server along side shopify. Is it possible to have basically two servers running with the same domain name, but with different content?

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Answer is NO.

If it is possible, use sub domain.

Points your primary domain eg `http://testlight.com` to shopify server.

Create a sub domain eg `http://images.testlight.com` which can be pointed to your own hosting server.

reference : https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/subdomain-redirect-143026